# Modifying core pool size of a ThreadPoolExecutor dynamically

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am in need to modify the core pool size of a fixed thread pool executor dynamically during my execution based on the load. I tried using the method setCorePoolSize() to alter the size dynamically and i do see that the value gets set using the setCorePoolSize() method, but the actual number of executing threads remains ambiguous.

Example :
I have nearly 100 threads submitted with my thred pool executor for which i had set my core pool size as 10. Now 10 threads are executing (say thread_1 to thread_10) and 90 (say thread_11 to thread_100) in queue. At this point what will happen (in terms of the number of threads executing in paraller) if i set the core pool size as 5?

Similarly vice versa. What will happen if i set the core pool size as 15?

Comment: It's all explained in the javadoc: *If the new value is smaller than the current value, excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle. If larger, new threads will, if needed, be started to execute any queued tasks.* Also, you're confusing threads and tasks.

Comment: "I am in need to modify the core pool size of a fixed thread pool executor dynamically during my execution based on the load." <-- not to play the devil's advocate here, but this looks like an XY problem. Threads are "cheap" enough nowadays, do you really need to resize the thread pool? Have you proven that reducing the thread pool on heavy loads results in better performance?

Comment: My scenario is that I have multiple thread pool executors running in my jvm. Each one dedicated to one thread class. (Eg: one for parsing, one for pushing data to an external server etc). Each of these operations have their own priority. Now based on the real time number of threads available in each executor pool, I want to resize the core pool size of the executors, so that I alwasy ensure that the executor executing the thread with the highest priority has more number in core pool size when my load across all the executors are too huge..